# Fill in Missing Values in Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say we have this dataset: Two students are enrolled in two different courses and attendance is taken for each `student`. I am interested in finding the `attendance_dates` for the `students` for which either one of them or both of them missed the respective `subject`. For the `subject` and the `attendance_dates` the `students` did not show up return `NULL`. For example: `Chris` missed `English` class on `2/5/2021` and both `Chris` and `Joseph` missed `Chemistry` and `English` on `2/6/2021`.

I am using postgreSQL!

```
subject            attendance_dates        student 
Chemistry             2/4/2021              Chris
Chemistry             2/4/2021              Joseph
English               2/4/2021              Chris
English               2/4/2021              Joseph
Chemistry             2/5/2021              Chris
Chemistry             2/5/2021              Joseph
English               2/5/2021              Joseph
Chemistry             2/7/2021              Chris
Chemistry             2/7/2021              Joseph
English               2/7/2021              Chris
English               2/7/2021              Joseph
```

What I have tried:

```
with cte as (
select subject,attendance_dates,student from my_table
)
,
dates as (
select * from generate_series('2021-02-04', '2021-02-07', interval '1 day')  AS more_dates
)

select subject_id,cast(more_dates as date)more_dates,student
from cte c
right join dates d 
on cast(more_date as date) = attendance_dates
```

Result:

```
subject            attendance_dates        student 
Chemistry             2/4/2021              Chris
Chemistry             2/4/2021              Joseph
English               2/4/2021              Chris
English               2/4/2021              Joseph
Chemistry             2/5/2021              Chris
Chemistry             2/5/2021              Joseph
English               2/5/2021              Joseph
                      2/6/2021                           <----------
Chemistry             2/7/2021              Chris
Chemistry             2/7/2021              Joseph
English               2/7/2021              Chris
English               2/7/2021              Joseph
```

Requested:

```
subject           attendance_dates          student 
Chemistry             2/4/2021               Chris
Chemistry             2/4/2021               Joseph
English               2/4/2021               Chris
English               2/4/2021               Joseph
Chemistry             2/5/2021               Chris
Chemistry             2/5/2021               Joseph
English               2/5/2021                         <------------
English               2/5/2021               Joseph
Chemistry             2/6/2021                         <-----------
Chemistry             2/6/2021                         <-----------
English               2/6/2021                         <-----------
English               2/6/2021                         <-----------
Chemistry             2/7/2021               Chris
Chemistry             2/7/2021               Joseph
English               2/7/2021               Chris
English               2/7/2021               Joseph
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you really want a flag on each day for each student and subject indicating whether or not the student attended.

Use `cross join` to create a row for all dates, subjects, and students.  Then bring in an flag to indicate whether the student attended on that day:

```
select d.date, su.subject, st.student,
       (t.student is not null) as attended_flag
from generate_series('2021-02-04', '2021-02-07', interval '1 day') d(dte) cross join
     (select distinct subject from my_table) su cross join
     (select distinct student from my_table) st left join
     my_table t
     on t.student = st.student and t.subject = su.subject and
        t.attendance_date = d.dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=80616f9206cdd61e98caa4a45dbd04cf) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, I get an error as follows: `syntax error at or near "st"`

Comment: @JakeWagner . . . I don't know where that `union all` came from.  I fixed the answer and added a db<>fiddle.